# How to dig to site wiithin links in scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I wrote a python class for scrapy like this:

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field
from scrapy.spider import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector

class MyItem(Item):
    content = Field()

class TestSpider(Spider):
    name = 'test_spider'
    allowed_domains = ['www.hamshahrionline.ir']
    start_urls = ['http://www.hamshahrionline.ir/']

    def parse(self, response):
        sel = Selector(response)
        h4 = sel.xpath("//h4/a/text()").extract()

    for t4 in h4:
            title4 = MyItem()
            title4['content'] = t4
            yield title4
```

I want to know how I can dig to the links of this contents and surf into other pages?

The second question:

Could you possibly tell me how to see content of links page by page from a web site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a [`CrawlSpider`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawlspider) instead of a regular `Spider` class. It supports the idea of [`Rules`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawling-rules) and [`LinkExtractors`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html), that can extract the links and follow them.

Example (following all the links that has `service/\w+` inside):

```
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.item import Item, Field


class MyItem(Item):
    content = Field()


class TestSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'test_spider'
    allowed_domains = ['hamshahrionline.ir']
    start_urls = ['http://www.hamshahrionline.ir']

    rules = (
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('service/\w+', ), ), callback='parse_item'),
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        print response.url

        item = MyItem()
        item['content'] = response.body
        return item
```

Comment: I think I should read the whole document in order to learn scrappy completely :).. thank you ...I'll check it

Comment: Pardon, If it reads a links that have service so does it read the sub links from that page again? thank you

Comment: @MortezaLSC there is a special `follow` argument to the [`Rule`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.contrib.spiders.Rule) which controls it.